ORA-02292: integrity constraint (CITY_COUNTRY_FK) violated - child record found
I am trying to make my all table columns in lowercase but the following error appears:
SQL> UPDATE COUNTRY SET country_code = LOWER(country_code);
UPDATE COUNTRY SET country_code = LOWER(country_code)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (OWNER.CITY_COUNTRY_FK) violated - child
record found

Here are my tables:
create table country(
country_code varchar2(2) PRIMARY KEY,
country nvarchar2(57) NOT NULL
);

create table city(
city_code varchar2(3) PRIMARY KEY,
country_code varchar2(3) CONSTRAINT city_country_fk references country(country_code) NOT NULL,
city varchar2(24) NOT NULL
);

Here is some sample data:
INSERT INTO COUNTRY VALUES ('US', 'United States');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY VALUES ('SR', 'Suriname');

INSERT INTO city(city_code,country_code,city) VALUES('BAF','US','Westfield');
INSERT INTO city(city_code,country_code,city) VALUES('BBB','US','Benson');
INSERT INTO city(city_code,country_code,city) VALUES('OEM','SR','Paloemeu');

Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25073835/10138734

My bad I was not able to open this link even with strong VPN because I am living in a sanctioned country

I am living in a sanctioned country ?? I'm living in such country too (RF), but I have no problems with opening SO... the answer by the link recommends to use Tom Kyte's cascading update script
